# How to pick up a random value from an enum class?

Tags: c++, random, enums

hello,

Been recently into C++ (C++14 to be precise), and I'me trying to get my way with enums, still have a bit of trouble figuring things out
Currently, trying to get a random value from an enum class that was constructed as such:

```
enum class Niveau {
  #define NIVEAU_DEF(NOM,VALEUR) NOM = VALEUR,
  #include "niveau.def"
  #undef NIVEAU_DEF
};
```

And here is the content of "niveau.def"

```
NIVEAU_DEF(I, 1)
NIVEAU_DEF(II, 2)
...
NIVEAU_DEF(IX, 9)
NIVEAU_DEF(X, 10)
```

Is it possible to pick up a random one of those enumerations using a method ? Or does this way of constructing an enum doesn't allow it?

Comment: When I see those roman numbers here I think this enumeration is an overkill. What is your actual task (not your solution for it)?

Comment: @MarekR Bit late, but to answer your question, the plan is to do a small game in which weapons, objects or whatever have a "tier" level, which is represented but roman numbers. "I" being the lowest and "X" the highest. That's the idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a XMacro already, you can just reuse it to create an array of the values and pick from it:

```
const Niveau niveau_vals[] = {
  #define NIVEAU_DEF(NOM,VALEUR) Niveau::VALEUR,
  #include "niveau.def"
  #undef NIVEAU_DEF
};
```

In newer versions of the language, you can make it a nice constexpr with `std::array`.

```
constexpr std::array niveau_vals = {
  #define NIVEAU_DEF(NOM,VALEUR) Niveau::VALEUR,
  #include "niveau.def"
  #undef NIVEAU_DEF
};
```

Comment: `std::array` or C-style array might be a better choice because size is know at the compile-time - no dynamic allocation is needed.

Comment: @Evg I was just in the process of adding this, but since OP is in C++14, sizing the std::array is akward, which is why I went with a std::vector by default. Good call on the C-style array.

Comment: C-style array then (`std::begin()` and `std::end()` work on C-style arrays, too).

Comment: Makes sense now that I see it! Thanks, it's working like a charm!